# Dipatching an action before mapStateToProps in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm working on a userProfile container component in react which displays some data after fething it from a server.

This is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PersonalInformationView from './PersonalInformationView';
import * as selectors from '../../../reducers';

    class PersonalInformationViewContainer extends React.Component{
        constructor(props, context){
            super(props, context);

        }

        render(){
            return (
                    <PersonalInformationView userProfile={this.props.userProfile}/>
            );
        }

    }


    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
        return {
            user: selectors.getUser(state),
            userProfile: selectors.getUserProfile(state)
        };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = () =>{
        return {

        };
    };
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PersonalInformationViewContainer);
```

The problem Im having is that I need to dipatch the action `FETCH_USER_PROFILE_STARTED` that calls a saga and brings the data. This needs to be done before calling the selector `getUserProfile` because Im getting an undefined as a result with the above code.

What is the best way to ensure I have finished fetching the data so the props.userProfile is not undefined in my component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add

```
if (!this.props.userProfile)
  return null;
```

at the beginning of your render method so that the component renders empty.

Or render a loading text or animation instead of null while waiting for the fetch.

Or don't render the component at all by putting the test higher in component hierarchy...

Technically, you could avoid calling the `getUserProfile` selector before the fetch starts but this would end up in an unnecessary complicated, ugly, unmaintainable and unreadable code... Why would you do that?

You actually **want** to call the selector and you **want** it to return `undefined` which is the simple truth...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one more question. Where should I call the dispatch for fetching the userprofile?

Comment: You could use the `componentDidMount` for example but it depends on your needs.